# Making specific folder accessible to user for 24 hour only

Tags: ubuntu-one, password

Is there possible to make some folder accessible to one user for 24 hours only with some password which is prescribed by me as the owner of material in folders.

I am a teaching assistant and I would like to use those 5 GB as a knowledge library for students. So I would like to make permissions for using material in folders for only 24 hours per one student. I would like to work it like that: I give to student password and he can access folders in Ubuntu just for 24 hours. After 24 hours he would have to get new password from me if he would like to use more material loaded in my Ubuntu account. This is the basic of idea.

Is it possible?

Comment: Interesting. What would prevent a student from copying the things out of the shared folder and continue using them beyond the intended period? Is that something you want to prevent?

Answer (score 1):

That would be a bad idea. What you should do instead, is to create a group for those students that should be allowed to access the files in that folder and then add and remove students from that group. This is fairly easy to do. You might have to script the adding and removal from the groups though.

Comment: As I read it, this is a question about Ubuntu One :)

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then the question needs to be edited, because that's a completely different matter. Nice catch, though. I think you may be right.

Comment: yes, thats what i want to prevent. in folders will be documents in non printable format and also non print screening format, so you would have to use it, read it from screen. documents will be interesting for students because they will be solved problems from tests. so student will have to buy password to read those documents.

is it possible to make something like that?

yes, question is for ubuntu one.

Comment: You're talking about literary DRM? That's difficult, but I think it will be even more difficult to find anyone in the Ubuntu community that would want to help create such a thing.